# Moving numbers in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to sort my data. I want to move the first numbers of the first row in the first "cell", the second number in the second, etc, no matters what is the header. I want to make this from the first row to the last.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

[Here is the original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uDhn.png)

Comment: You should look at the help for `sort` and `order` by typing `?sort` and `?order`

Comment: You can do `t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun its working perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`) to subset the non-NA elements, followed by the `NA` elements, concatenate it (`c(`), transpose (`t`) the output and assign it to original dataset

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```